# Create a function named “calc_circle_area” in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

It will take an integer named "radius" as the function input, then return the area of the circle with that radius. The return value is type of numeric with 2 decimal point.
Use pi = 3.14159

Comment: Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function calc_circle_area(radius int)
   returns numeric
   language plpgsql
  as
$circle_area$
declare 
  pi numeric := 3.14159;
begin
  return round((radius * radius * pi), 2);
end;
$circle_area$
```

> ```
> select calc_circle_area(100)
> ```

| calc_circle_area |
| --- |
| 31415.90 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=72b7a6ffca15f36923dd35d232b75334)*